# Why is there significant gas costs associated with call and delegate call?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, delegatecall, library

I've been trying to understanding why Ethereum doesn't have a significant on chain package/library ecosystem despite having the capacity to do so via `delegatecall` or `call` to an `ImplementationContract` or `ImplementationLibrary` function respectively as per [this article](https://www.blocksism.com/solidity-delegatecall-call-library/).

The only reason I can think off is the relatively high gas costs of 700 for `call` and `delegatecall` as per [EIP-150](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-150), which makes it much cheaper gas wise to simply copy paste functions directly into your contract than to reference a method in another `contract` or `library` using `delegatecall` or `call` respectively. In fact there should be no gas cost associated with either opcode to disincentivise copy pasting and incentivise the use of on-chain `library`/`contract`s.

Is this analysis correct? and if so why don't they reduce gas costs associated with those opcodes to encourage an on-chain open source library ecosystem? which should also help space wise by not having to duplicate frequently used functions.

Answer (score 3):

The gas cost comes from the state lookup. To load the code that should be run for a `call` or `delegatecall` it is required to perform a lookup in the state tree. If these costs are removed it is easy to perform a denial of service attack on Ethereum.

Some more information on this can be founds in the lates gas costs EIP: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2929#sstore-gas-cost-change

Comment: That's fair, but shouldn't frequently accessed libraries be stored in RAM for cheap fast access, also is there a gas cost associated with loading the CallingContract/MainContract? and if so is that gas cost the same as loading the ImplementationContract/Library when using delegate/call?

Comment: Subsequent loading costs less. With EIP-2929 the repeated loading of storage and code was lowered to 100 gas. But even access from RAM still have some processing overhead that has to be paid for to avoid attack vectors. It was discussed in the past to lower the gas costs for calling precompiles: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2046.

Comment: So there's no gas efficient way to build out an on-chain library ecosystem with the current EVM?

Comment: I don't think that gas efficiency is the main blocker (but that is a very personal opinion). Else on other chains that have lower gas costs it would still be possible. Also 3000 gas (700 + 2300) are not that much gas in complex cases. It might rather be related to verifyability and keeping logic contained. Packaging structures also open up supply chain attacks. In general I think this is one of the goals of the OpenZepplin team and it would be worth to get their input.

Answer (score 0):

Call and delegatecall are low level function calls which are quite optimized form the gas usage perspective but it has it's own drawbacks for example delegatecall would work fine only when the state variables of the contracts are declared in the same order otherwise state variables would shown unexpected values. The use cases of using delegate call also need to be explored well. Because the logic in the called can be changed without doing any modification from the main function.